# Why can't I save a database transaction using SubSonic?

Tags: c#, subsonic

I have a table called jobs and I can get data out of the table with no problems but saving is causing issues.  Here is the code and the error:

```
        Job job = new Job(JobId);

        job.Name = txtName.Text;
        job.SimsCustCode = txtSimsCustCode.Text;
        job.Mode = cboMode.Text;
        job.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(nudInterval.Text);
        job.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(chkEnabled.Checked);

        job.SourceHost = txtSourceHostName.Text;
        job.SourceType = cboSourceType.Text;
        job.SourceUsername = txtSourceUsername.Text;
        job.SourcePassword = txtSourcePassword.Text;
        job.SourceDirectory = txtSourceDirectory.Text;
        job.SourceIgnoreExtension = txtSourceIgnoreExtension.Text;

        job.TargetHost = txtTargetHostName.Text;
        job.TargetType = cboTargetType.Text;
        job.TargetUsername = txtTargetUsername.Text;
        job.TargetPassword = txtTargetPassword.Text;
        job.TargetDirectory = txtTargetDirectory.Text;
        job.TargetTempExtension = txtTargetTempExtension.Text;

        job.Save();
```

Here is the error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'interval) VALUES('adf','adsf','inbound','ftp','','','','','','ftp','','','','','' at line 1
```

To clarify, if I edit an existing job it works fine, it's only saving new jobs that fails.

Here is the schema:

Table   Create Table

---

jobs    CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
          `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
          `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
          `sims_cust_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
          `mode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
          `source_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
          `source_host` varchar(100) default NULL,
          `source_username` varchar(50) default NULL,
          `source_password` varchar(50) default NULL,
          `source_directory` varchar(100) default NULL,
          `source_ignore_extension` varchar(10) default NULL,
          `target_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
          `target_host` varchar(100) default NULL,
          `target_username` varchar(50) default NULL,
          `target_password` varchar(50) default NULL,
          `target_directory` varchar(100) default NULL,
          `target_temp_extension` varchar(10) default NULL,
          `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
          `interval` int(11) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a value isn't being parsed right - I need to see the SQL schema and also the SQL that's being generated - do you have a profiler up? Something that allows you to watch what's happening?

Interval is a MySQL reserved word :) - can you enter a bug on this? We should catch that...

Comment: If you're above version 5.0.37 you can use this:
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html

From your schema I'd guess either enabled or interval has an invalid value.

Comment: Adam, that's what i figured but it works fine if i'm updating and existing record, just not adding a new one.

Comment: Adam, I tried that profiling tool but that doesn't seem to give me the commands that are going from my studio app to mysql.  I think i need some kind of profiler on my app to see what it is communicating out.

Comment: interval was a reserved mysql word.  changed that and it's all good now.